# Sitecore User Group Deutschland - SUGDE Frankfurt 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Die Sitecore Usergroup Deutschland trifft sich zum dritten Mal im Jahr 2017! Für dieses Treffen am 31. August 2017 haben wir eine ganz besondere Location in Frankfurt gefunden. Ein Kino,... lasste uch überraschen!

Unsere Vorträge:

- Christian Hahn, ecx.io: Sitecore E-Commerce vom Allgemeinen bis zum technischen Deepdive
- Mark Cassidy, cassidy consult: Buses and Queues with Sitecore & Azure
- Sebastian Winter, Metro SYSTEMS AG: 100% Availability – Scale your System landscape and procecesses waterproof
- Benjamin Gabriel & Philipp Nestler, Namics: Diskussion: Sitecore-Entwicklung im Team - Tools und Prozesse

Der Vorstand berichtet über die Sitecore Usergroup Deutschland e.V.
Jetzt noch schnell ein Ticket sichern! Wir freuen uns auf euch!

Time: Thu, 31 Aug 2017, 01:00 PM (CEST)  - Thu, 31 Aug 2017, 05:30 PM (CEST)
11:00 - 15:30 UTC

Location: Erfeos Erben, Frankfurt am Main, Germany

More information: https://www.xing.com/events/sitecore-usergroup-deutschland-frankfurt-1831054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

Community Promotion has begun.